# Made an oupsie while testing some protection and executed rm /usr/bin/clang*

Tags: ubuntu, apt, clang, llvm

I  deleted clang. I tried to use apt to uninstall clang, and then re-install it but I get this error:

```
Setting up clang (1:3.8-33ubuntu3.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/clang++ doesn't 
exist
dpkg: error processing package clang (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 clang
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried also using apt to remove llvm and reinstall it knowing it should also install clang.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, since further versions are un-workingly buggy for me.

Here's some more info:

```
main@ws001:~$ whereis clang
clang: /usr/bin/clang #this is obviously broken
main@ws001:~$ which clang
```

apt-cache depends clang

```
clang
  Depends: clang-3.8
  Breaks: <clang-3.2>
  Breaks: <clang-3.3>
  Breaks: <clang-3.4>
  Breaks: clang-3.5
  Replaces: clang
  Replaces: <clang-3.2>
  Replaces: <clang-3.3>
  Replaces: <clang-3.4>
  Replaces: clang-3.5
```

Comment: You probably need to re-install the underlying dependency package (likely `clang-3.8` - but confirm with `apt-cache depends clang`)

Answer (score 1):

You could reinstall the packages with the `--force-overwrite` flag:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/clang*
```

Look at the cache for older versions before you use `clang*`.

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package clang (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2`

Comment: You could search for the failing command in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/clang.{postinst,prerm}`. I cannot reproduce your error with the provided rm command. Did you do something else?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Clang is already installed but linked up with other name.

If that code gives you such error:

```bsh
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
./clang.postinst
```

```
update-alternatives: ошибка: альтернативный путь /usr/bin/clang++ не существует
```

The solution will be to edit clang.postinst.
Change that:

```bsh
update-alternatives --quiet \
   --install /usr/bin/c++ \
        c++ \
        /usr/bin/clang++ \
        $prio

update-alternatives --quiet \
    --install /usr/bin/cc \
        cc \
        /usr/bin/clang \
        $prio
```

To that:

```bsh
update-alternatives --quiet \
   --install /usr/bin/clang++ \
        clang++ \
        /usr/bin/c++ \
        $prio

update-alternatives --quiet \
    --install /usr/bin/clang \
        clang \
        /usr/bin/cc \
        $prio
```

Than run it and test clang:

```
./clang.postinst

clang
```

```
clang: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved through OS re-install. If anyone encounters this and manages to solve it, please do let me know how.